# Issue with emailing

Tags: email, centos6

Ok, so I have a small php script that sends an confirmation email after signup.. but it isn't working.. I know it isn't the code as the script works any where else, but I have made sure sendmail is installed, as well as checked my php.ini file.. The thing is, if an email is sent from 1 local email to another it will work, but it wont work sending to outside website providers.. here is an image of what I mean.

[image: http://imgur.com/IjYnd]

Hopefully that can help.. I was using dovecot but just switched it over to Courier i didn't know if it would solve the problem, but I can see now it didn't :/

Here is a link to a paste of my maillog. http://pastebin.com/QsZq9RbR

Also I did find a log named maillog-20121216 so i opened it up and it has this, which isn't in the pastebin post

```
Dec 17 00:00:40 cserver exim[12268]: 2012-12-17 00:00:40 cwd=/ 2 args: /usr/sbin/exim -bV
Dec 17 00:00:40 cserver exim[12268]: 2012-12-17 00:00:40 Cannot open main log file "/var/log/exim_mainlog": No such file or directory: euid=0 egid=0
Dec 17 00:00:40 cserver exim[12268]: exim: could not open panic log - aborting: see message(s) above
Dec 17 00:00:41 cserver exim[12273]: 2012-12-17 00:00:41 cwd=/ 4 args: /usr/sbin/exim -bV -C /etc/exim.conf.buildtest.work.utMeQPXmJY3yr_Rm
Dec 17 00:00:41 cserver exim[12273]: 2012-12-17 00:00:41 Cannot open main log file "/var/log/exim_mainlog": No such file or directory: euid=0 egid=0
Dec 17 00:00:41 cserver exim[12273]: exim: could not open panic log - aborting: see message(s) above
```

This the output of exim_paniclog

```
2012-12-17 09:46:32 socket bind() to port 25 for address (any IPv6) failed: Address already in use: daemon abandoned
2012-12-18 05:33:01 1TkuTt-00038k-O2 User 0 set for local_delivery transport is on the never_users list
2012-12-18 06:36:10 1TkvT0-0003JX-NS User 0 set for local_delivery transport is on the never_users list
2012-12-18 07:29:52 1TkvT0-0003JX-NS User 0 set for local_delivery transport is on the never_users list
2012-12-18 08:29:52 1TkuTt-00038k-O2 User 0 set for local_delivery transport is on the never_users list
2012-12-18 08:39:20 1TkxOC-0003eU-C6 User 0 set for local_delivery transport is on the never_users list
2012-12-18 09:36:11 1TkyHC-0003nd-T1 User 0 set for local_delivery transport is on the never_users list
2012-12-18 10:41:26 1TkvT0-0003JX-NS User 0 set for local_delivery transport is on the never_users list
2012-12-18 12:29:52 1TkuTt-00038k-O2 User 0 set for local_delivery transport is on the never_users list
2012-12-18 15:29:52 1TkuTt-00038k-O2 User 0 set for local_delivery transport is on the never_users list
2012-12-18 19:33:02 1TkyHC-0003nd-T1 User 0 set for local_delivery transport is on the never_users list
2012-12-18 20:00:14 1Tl817-0005tq-WA User 0 set for local_delivery transport is on the never_users list
2012-12-18 20:16:54 socket bind() to port 25 for address (any IPv6) failed: Address already in use: daemon abandoned
```

Comment: Have you checked /var/log/maillog for any errors?

Comment: You may want to disable your firewall and try again.

Comment: You should have obscured the user name and left the domain name visible.

Comment: @MichaelHampton was gmail and yahoo

Comment: @Safado ahh yeah I have checked it but have no idea what any of it means. http://pastebin.com/QsZq9RbR

Comment: Do you have SELinux enabled? What's the output of the `getenforce` command? If it's `Enforcing` you probably need to run `setsebool -P httpd_can_sendmail=1` to allow your webserver to send outgoing mails.

Comment: @Oldskool output of `getenforce` is disabled

Comment: @Zim3r i disabled the firewall and it still doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that local delivery is happening and remote email account mails are not getting delivered. 
Can you stop firewall and try to send the mail?

Also check your `/etc/resolv.conf` file and use 8.8.8.8 and try again. It is possibly due to firewall.

Try sending mail to your gmail or yahoo account from the Shell (command line) of the server. Post the out put and logs `(/var/log/mail.log`) too.

Comment: I did stop the firewall and tried, it still did not work, so I am not sure what could be going on. Nothing was added to the `maillog` after running the mail command, nor did it send the email upon sending it just said `EOT` which I assume is a confirmation but I do not know for sure. I am new to all this owning a server stuff :/

Comment: as I can see you are using cpanel for managing you server. also did you check your resolv.conf file. use public resolver as I mentioned above and try again.

Comment: I was told that if I changed that file I would be in breech of contract with my VPS provider, so there isn't much i can do about that.

Comment: I am not sure what kind of VPS provider is this and I would also like to know if you are running csf then disable it using csf -x ... also add another nameserver entry to the resolve.conf file as "nameserver 8.8.8.8" do not remove existing one so this way you are not violating anything.. I hope this is convenient ..

Comment: how do I check if I am running csf? when i try that command it says command not found.

Comment: No i was not running CSF, I googled it and found out what it was I did install it and then disable it and it didn't do anything.. I am beginning to feel this is a lost cause :/

Comment: I figured out the issue, my VPS provider had SMTP blocked but i got them to unblock it, then your csf -x and resolv make it work